# How to get nuget packages videolibrary (libvideo) to work with unity?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, nuget, video-library

This may be a basic question but I am new to Visual studio and untiy. I have installed the videolibrary(https://github.com/omansak/libvideo) package using nuget package manager in Visual studio, but it keeps says reference not found when I add the "using VideoLibrary" code.

I have tried updating the reference dependencies and also tried in the console "update-package -reinstall". It work immediately after "update-package -reinstall" in VS but doesn't reflect in Unity. If I close VS and reopen the issue comes back. Since its working in VS at least immediately after and not in unity I suspect the installation or package unloading should happen also in unity is some way.

I think I am missing something in the procedure of installing this in unity. Help appreciated.

I have tried:
Updating the references.
Reinstalling the package
Tried in another computer
Converting to nodes all the references

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use that video library? If this library is causing you issues, are you aware there is a video player included in Unity by default?

Comment: have you compiled it into a library and put it in the unity asset structure?

Comment: I am needing that library as it lets me get info on youtube videos.

Comment: Compiled it into a library and add it as a asset? How do i compile it as a library? Sry a little new.